Early 60's British movie- Boy falls out of train, woman drowned in bathtub
Early 60's B&W British movie 
Memorable scenes: Boy on train asking over and over for candy or something keeps pulling at door which opens and he falls out.
Later a woman in a bathtub takes sleeping pills, drinks alcohol. She mocks and insults a man who's in the room. He waits until she passes out and pulls her by the feet until she drowns.
I think it was on a double bill with "A Hard Day's Night"

Return from the Ashes, a British B&W thriller from 1965. From IMDb:

Stanislaus Pilgrin, a Polish chess master and handsome gigolo, marries wealthy Jewish widow, Dr. Michele Wolf, an X-ray technician and has an affair with her step-daughter, Fabienne and then plots to murder them both in a scheme that will have him inherit their money.

In the beginning, Michele apathetically witnesses an accident while on a train: a young boy keeps kicking a door; his mother offers him a chocolate bar, but the boy keeps playing with the door which then opens and he falls off the train. And later on in the film:

While taking a bath after consuming alcohol and barbiturates, the jealous Fabi tells Stan her plan for killing her step-mother. [...] Though it is not clear if Fabi is serious, the amoral Stan drowns her in the bathtub in such a way that it looks like an accident related to an overdose, and then carries out her plan.

Here's the opening sequence where the boy falls off the train:




Thank you, thank you, thank you!
This scene freaked me out as a child.
Mystery solved
